# How to get a Windows Server to tell a LINUX server to Run a Script?

Tags: linux, windows, remote-access

How can I get a Windows server to tell a LINUX server to run a script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using SSH.  You can specify a command to run on the command-line, and you can set up SSH keys so that you don't need to enter a password every time.

You can get OpenSSH for Windows from [the full Cygwin environment](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [just the parts you need](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/).  A good SSH client for interactive use is [PuTTY](http://chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

Here is a good guide to [running remote commands](http://bashcurescancer.com/run_remote_commands_with_ssh.html) and [setting up SSH keys](http://bashcurescancer.com/setting_up_ssh_keys_for_access_without_password.html).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs, you could also make the script web accessible, such as putting a php wrapper on it, then have the Windows host (or any other host for that matter) trigger the script at the interval you need.

Of course, make sure you have proper security procedures in place if you choose to go this route.